# I can't change the value of a slider by code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code for the variables:

```
public Slider healthSlider;
public Slider thirstSlider;
public Slider hungerSlider;
public float health;
public float hunger;
public float thirst;
```

This is a scriptable object

```
public Descriptions apple;
```

I also did this:

```
healthSlider.value = health;
thirstSlider.value = thirst;
hungerSlider.value = hunger;
health = Mathf.Clamp(health, 0f, 100f);
thirst = Mathf.Clamp(thirst, 0f, 100f);
hunger = Mathf.Clamp(hunger, 0f, 100f);
```

And this is where we edit the slider's value:

```
public void Apple()
{
hunger = apple.hunger + hunger;
thirst = apple.thirst + thirst;
health = apple.health + health;
}
```

I also tried this But it didn't work:

```
public void Apple()
{
hunger += apple.hunger;
thirst += apple.thirst;
health += apple.health;
}
```

I also tried access it directly like this, but it didn't work:

```
hungerSlider.value += 0.1f;
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while now but i can't figure it out, any help would be appreciated!Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`float` is a **value** type, **NOT** a reference type!

When you do

> And this is where we edit the slider's value:
>
> ```
> public void Apple()
> {
>     hunger = apple.hunger + hunger;
>     thirst = apple.thirst + thirst;
>     health = apple.health + health;
> }
> ```

-> **No, it is not.** What you are doing here is updating your local fields `hunger`, `thirst` and `health`. These are just `float` fields and in no way connected to your sliders.

→ This will not affect the sliders in any way until you assign these values back to them e.g. via

```
hungerSlider.value = hunger;
```

---

Also to

> I also tried access it directly like this, but it didn't work:
>
> ```
> hungerSlider.value += 0.1f;
> ```

Well, from your clamping I would assume your sliders go from `0` to `100` so a change of `0.1f` would be barely notable since it is only 1/1000 of the total slider range.

---

It should probably rather be something like

```
public void Apple()
{
    hungerSlider.value += apple.hunger;
    thirstSlider.value += apple.thirst;
    healthSlider.value += apple.health;
}
```

don't use your local fields mirroring the slider values at all - they only cause confusion. Except when you do a lot of changes/calculations on one value you would do them in a local variable that only exists inside that method and then assign it back to the slider property in one go e.g.

```
var hunger = hungerSlider.value;
hunger += apple.hunger;
hunger = Mathf.Clamp(hunger, 0, 100);
hungerSlider.value = hunger;
```

---

Alternatively you could convert your local fields to [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and do e.g.

```
public float Hunger
{
    get { return hungerSlider.value; }
    set 
    {
        value = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 100);
        hungerSlider.value = value;
    }
}
```

This means everytime you access the value of `Hunger` what you actually get is `hungerSlider.value`. And the other way round everytime you assign a new value to `Hunger` you actually clamp it first and then assign it to `hungerSlider.value`.

doing this you now could e.g. simply do

```
public void Apple()
{
    Hunger += apple.hunger;
    // etc
}
```